# Google Guice: use injected factory to instantiate multiple objects in a class?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(BaseClass.class, ImplementingClass.class).build(FactoryClass.class));
    }
}

public class AnotherClass {
    @Inject
    private FactoryClass factoryClass;

    private BaseClass firstBaseObject = factoryClass.create("some_parameter");
    private BaseClass secondBaseObject = factoryClass.create("another_parameter");

    public void processSomething() {
        // ... do something that requires both firstBaseObject and secondBaseObject to already be initialized on each call
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to have access to both `firstBaseObject` and `secondBaseObject` already on each call of `processSomething()`? Each call of `processSomething()` depends on these two objects already being instantiated, and they are huge objects with a lot of metadata. i.e. can I ensure somehow that `factoryClass` is already instantiated when these two lines are hit?:

```
    private BaseClass firstBaseObject = factoryClass.create("some_parameter");
    private BaseClass secondBaseObject = factoryClass.create("another_parameter");
```

I'm getting NullPointerExceptions on these two lines because `factoryClass` is null.

Let me know if you need more information, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code

```
public class AnotherClass {
    private final BaseClass firstBaseObject;
    private final BaseClass secondBaseObject;

    @Inject
    public AnotherClass(FactoryClass factoryClass) {
       firstBaseObject = factoryClass.create("some_parameter");
       secondBaseObject = factoryClass.create("another_parameter");
    }

    public void processSomething() {
        // ... do something that requires both firstBaseObject and secondBaseObject to already be initialized on each call
    }
}
```

You can't use field or method injections, because injection in factoryClass be after filling firstBaseObject and secondBaseObject.

OR

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        ...
        bind(BaseClass.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("firstBaseObject"))
        .toInstance(factoryClass.create("some_parameter"));

        bind(BaseClass.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("secondBaseObject"))
        .toInstance(factoryClass.create("another_parameter"));
    }
}

public class AnotherClass {
    @Inject
    @Named("firstBaseObject")
    private BaseClass firstBaseObject;
    @Inject
    @Named("secondBaseObject")
    private BaseClass secondBaseObject;

    public void processSomething() {
        // ... do something that requires both firstBaseObject and secondBaseObject to already be initialized on each call
    }
}
```